# ActionMailer and Gmail:: Very Slow to send email from application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I've been using [this tutorial](https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/rails-4-simple-form-and-mail-form-to-make-contact-form/) to build a contact form for an application (Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.1). The email address that is being used is a gmail one. I'm not sure how much influence this could have over this problem, however this tutorial indicates using Devise (and for this project, I have to use a scratch build log in system that is not Devise)

The code works (as in, a confirmation that the email has been sent appears and no errors are recorded in the development log) but the email never comes through. I've only tested this in development this far.

My colleague working on a similar project has said that it took awhile (as in, a few hours to a day) for his application form to send out. I've checked [other stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216742/rails-mailer-is-not-actually-sending-emails) questions for the same problem but it's so far not been all that useful.

This is the set up in my config/development.rb part (minus log in details of course)

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 address: "smtp.gmail.com",
 port: "587",
 domain: "gmail.com",
 authentication: "plain",
 enable_starttls_auto: true,
 user_name: 'my_user_name_is_here',
 password: 'my_password_is_here'
}
```

Is this a known issue, or am I missing the obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gmail is very uptight about these things and I've experienced the same sort of thing in my projects. What you can try to do is to login to that Gmail account directly and verify that the email was indeed sent.

But more than likely Gmail is preventing you from logging in remotely because your application  is not deemed "secure" enough. If this is the case then go to this website: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 , and click on the "Unlock Captcha" option while logged in to your gmail, then try again, that should help.